# Double pointer to a contiguous 2D array memory location issue

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I have the following code in C language and can't figure out why an exception (memory access violation) is being thrown.
In my understanding using the double-pointer, I should be able to access the array via indexing since it is contiguous.
My end goal is to store some values in array_double via pointers only.

```c
uint8_t array_double[4][15];
uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;
uint8_t **double_ptr = &single_ptr;
uint8_t value;

value = double_ptr[0][14]; // this works
value = double_ptr[1][0]; // throws an exception

double_ptr[0][14] = write_value; // this works
double_ptr[1][0] = write_value; // throws an exception
```

Comment: what exception? It this C or C++? They are two different languages

Comment: Are you using C or C++? `uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;` shouldn't even compile in C++.

Comment: Memory access violation I debugged using visual studio. The language is C

Comment: `&single_ptr` is a pointer to the variable `single_ptr`. That pointer is totally unrelated to `array_double`. Besides, arrays of arrays never decay to pointers to pointers, they are just not the same thing.

Comment: `uint8_t **double_ptr` is not synonymous with `uint8_t array_double[4][15];` For one thing, the compiler has no idea of the width of each row.

Comment: Enable all warnings.  `uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;` is bad.  Something like "warning: initialization of 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} from incompatible pointer type 'uint8_t (*)[15]' {aka 'unsigned char (*)[15]'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" expected.

Comment: How should I be able to store value is array_double using pointers only. e.g at location array_double[1][0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These declarations of pointers

```
uint8_t array_double[4][15];
uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;
uint8_t **double_ptr = &single_ptr;
```

are incorrect.

For starters according to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
> object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The type of elements of this array

```
uint8_t array_double[4][15];
```

is `uint8_t[15]`. So a pointer to the initial element of the array has the type `uint8_t( * )[15]`.

Thus a valid declaration of `single_ptr` using the array `array_double` as an initializer will look like

```
uint8_t ( *single_ptr )[15] = array_double;
```

A pointer to `single_ptr` will look like

```
uint8_t ( **double_ptr )[15] = &single_ptr;
```

Using the pointer `single_ptr` you could write

```
value = single_ptr[0][14];
```

Using the pointer `double_ptr` you could write

```
value = ( *double_ptr )[1][0];
```

To set elements of the array using `single_ptr` you could write

```
single_ptr[0][14] = write_value;
```

To set elements of the array using `double_ptr` you could write

```
( *double_ptr )[1][0] = write_value;
```

To make it more clear let's consider the following assignment statement

```
value = single_ptr[0][14];
```

The expression `single_ptr[0]` yields the first element of the array `array_double` that represents a one-dimensional array of the type `uint8_t[15]` - the first element of the array `array_double`. The one-dimensional array specified by the expression `single_ptr[0]` used in the subscript expression single_ptr[0][4] in turn is implicitly converted to the first element of the one-dimensional array to which is applied the subscript operator. You could introduce intermediate variables the following way

```
// single_ptr[0] has the type uint8_t[15]
// and used as an expression in the statement below
// is implicitly converted to pointer to the element type 
// that is to a pointer of the type uint8_t *`
uint8_t *row = signle_ptr[0]; 
value = row[14];
```

Answer (score 3):

> [How should I be able to store value (in) `array_double` using pointers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835683/double-pointer-to-a-contiguous-2d-array-memory-location-issue/68835928?noredirect=1#comment121652873_68835683).

Enable all warnings to save time.

`uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;` is bad code as it initializes with the wrong type.

---

Define a pointer of the correct type to the first element of the array `array_double[]`.
`uint8_t (*single_ptr)[C]` is a [pointer to array C of uint8_t](https://cdecl.org/?q=unsigned+char+%28*single_ptr%29%5B3%5D)

```
// Reading example
#define R 2
#define C 3
int main(void) {
  uint8_t array_double[R][C] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
  uint8_t (*single_ptr)[C] = array_double;
  printf("%d\n", single_ptr[0][1]);
  printf("%d\n", single_ptr[1][0]);
}
```

Output

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 1):

`double_ptr` points to a single object: the variable `single_ptr`. Using pointer arithmetic `double_ptr[1]`, you go outside the bounds of that single object. Accessing that memory results in undefined behaviour.

Furthermore:

> ```
> uint8_t *single_ptr = array_double;
> ```

The type of the variable doesn't match with the initialiser. The program is ill-formed

---

If you really want to use pointer to a pointer with a 2D array, then you need to have an array of pointers:

```
uint8_t *ptrs[4];
for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ptrs[i] = array_double[i];
}
uint8_t **double_ptr = ptrs;
value = double_ptr[1][0]; // OK
```

---

Instead of a pointer to pointer, you could use a pointer to an array:

```
typedef uint8_t Array[15];
Array* array_pointer = array_double;
value = array_pointer[1][0]; // OK
```

---

Or you could write a function like this:

```
void foo(size_t x, size_t y, uint8_t array_double[x][y])
{
    assert(x > 1 && y > 0);
    uint8_t value = array_double[1][0]; // OK
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t array_double[4][15];
    foo(4, 15, array_double);
}
```

---

P.S. I recommend against calling a pointer to pointer a "double pointer" as that can be assumed to mean `double*` when out of context.